# Extracting frame every 30 seconds using FFmpeg is slow

Tags: performance, ffmpeg

We are extracting frame every 30 seconds from mp4 file with following FFmpeg command :

`ffmpeg -vsync 0 -i file.mp4 -vf fps=1,select='not(mod(t,30))' -frame_pts 1 temp\file.%d.jpg`

We are using vsync and frame_pts options since we need frame's position w.r.t. seconds in output file names. It is running slow. It takes around 90 seconds to extract around ~235 images from ~118 minutes (259 MB) mp4 file. CPU usage while running this command goes 100%.

We are using this command in multi-threaded java application. During load test, we found that with 10 threads running this command simultaneously, time to complete this command is 5-15 minutes.

Is there any way to improve performance of this FFmpeg command ?

Comment: I don't know the internals of ffmpeg, but this command line *looks* like it's basically playing (decoding) the whole file and rendering just some of the frames (to some files instead of the screen). If the input is a 118 minute video, then 90 seconds of cpu time doesn't sound too bad.

Comment: 259mb (millibits) or 259 MB (megabytes)? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte

Comment: It is 259MB (Megabytes) file. 90 seconds time is for single run. When we run 10 threads of ffmpeg command, performance degrades, it takes 5-15 minutes for each of 10 commands.